# .Net based win application and License issue

Tags: .net

i don't know how to implement License technique for any dotnet apps. which will work as a trial version. also like to know how dll library can use License technique as a result only valid user can use that dll....other user can not use just copying to their project. i need a good start as a beginner.....so please point me to some good article on License technique which give in-depth knowledge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some software that will do what you want and it is highly regarded:
http://xheo.com/products/copy-protection?gclid=CN6ruvzh0qgCFYbb4AodwR3_gQ

Basically, for licensing and trial software solutions, you are going to need a third-party utility like the one I listed above.  Do your research on which one offers the right choices for you and then purchase it.